# Is there a way to use tailwind only in certain pages of my React application?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have built a react application based on Bootstrap 5. But I really liked a login page from my friend's site which is in Tailwind. I want to avoid clash of styles and keep both of the react files with their isolated css files.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the play CDN.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
```

[Here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn) is the documentation

---

Alternatively, you can load Tailwind per the documentation with a prefix

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

[Here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) is the documentation for that. Doing it this way will make all classes in Tailwind use tw-, which will prevent clashes. I am currently using it this way.